# Can we use htaccess to run php script every minute without access to page directly?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm developing website that will run php script every minute without access to that page directly. Almost people said that I have to used cron job; but my domain doesn't have function cron job to do like other domain. So what I want to know is can we use other methods beside of cron job? For example, htaccess. Does it is possible?

Thank in advance.

Comment: `.htaccess` has nothing to do with this.

Comment: try searching here and Google, etc, for "alternative to cron" and other variants. What do you need it to do (briefly)?

Comment: Is it a Linux based host? If so, I'd be surprised if there's no cron - ssh in and type `crontab -e` and see if you get an editor.

Comment: @calcinai: where do i have to type crontab -e?

Comment: You'll need an ssh client.  If you're on a unix system you'll have one built in, if you use Windows, download PuTTY.

Comment: @calcinai: I already downloaded and installed it. How does it work?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the .htaccess file simply helps control Apache's configurations for your website. You can't launch jobs using that. Using cron is the best way to do what you want to do. If you don't have access to cron jobs, you could have a web page that controls that background worker by executing a shell command with like `exec()` or `passthru()` and manage the timer yoursel This is much more risky, since any error in your script might throw things off. You would have to manage the lifecycle of that background worker completely manually.

Maybe there are other scripts out there that might do what you want, but forget the .htaccess file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i will search more about cron job.